# What is the proper way to allocate memory in C for different data types?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I am reading an image into dynamically allocated array , the image pixel type can be anyone of the following types:

```
typedef enum {
              Byte = 1,//unsigned char
              Int32 = 2,//int
              Float32 = 3,//float
              Float64 = 4//double 
}DataType;
```

I am thinking using `switch` block to allocate the memory on a `void` pointer:

```
int NumPix = GetImageSize(Image);
DataType theDataType  = GetImageDataType(Image);
void *data;
switch (theDataType)
{
    case Byte:
      data = (unsigned char *)malloc(NumPix * sizeof(unsigned char));
      break;
    case Int32:
     data = (int *)malloc(NumPix * sizeof(int));
     break;
    case Float32:
     data = (float *)malloc(NumPix * sizeof(float));
     break;
    case Float64 :
     data = (double*)malloc(NumPix * sizeof(double));
     break; 


}
// do something with data
free(data);
```

Is this way OK in the sense of being legit? Is there another way doing this with less code and more generic approach?

Comment: Of possible interest is [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) Particularly here, since `malloc()` returns `void*` anyway and the target is `void *data` and there will be no memory later of the cast you made.

Comment: Technically, `int` doesn't have to be 32 bits. You can check if the optional [fixed-width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) exists in your implementation (very likely) and use them instead.

Comment: I see nothing else wrong with your code. However, I doubt that it is meaningful to create one function to handle all 4 cases, as you would often have to check `theDataType` and conditionally call code. Therefore, I believe it would be more meaningful to have 4 separate functions that are each specialised on a single data type and then call that function conditionally. That way, you only have one branch instead of many branches. [Branches are expensive in terms of performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/12149471).

Comment: Note that in C++, in order to create 4 specialised functions for each data type, you can simply write 1 function with a template parameter. The compiler will then automatically create 4 functions for you, one for every possible data type. However, since you have tagged the question C and not C++, I will not discuss this possiblity further (unless you ask).

Comment: Presumably somewhere you also have `union { uchar *u; int *i; float *f; double *d } t` (or similar). So you can just do `switch(theDataType) { case Byte: t.u = malloc( NumPix * sizeof *t.u); ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to know the size of a pixel in many places. So define a function to calculate the pixel size and use it each time you need it.

```
size_t pixel_size(DataType type) {
    switch (type) {
    case Byte: return sizeof(unsigned char);
    case Int32: return sizeof(unsigned int); // Shouldn't this be uint32_t?
    case Float32: return sizeof(float);
    case Float64: return sizeof(double);
    }
}

// Allocate an image with indeterminate content.
// Return NULL if the allocation fails.
void *allocate_indeterminate_image(DataType type, size_t x, size_t y) {
    size_t pixel_count = x * y; // overflow checking omitted
    size_t byte_count = pixel_count * pixel_size(type); // overflow checking omitted;
    return malloc(byte_count);
}

// Allocate an image with all-bits-zero. On almost every platform,
// this means that each pixel has the value 0 (+0.0 for floats).
// Return NULL if the allocation fails.
void *allocate_blank_image(DataType type, size_t x, size_t y) {
    size_t pixel_count = x * y; // overflow checking omitted
    size_t bytes_per_pixel = pixel_size(type);
    return calloc(pixel_count, bytes_per_pixel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your program a bit, in a way I use here for other things, and I will left it here as a maybe useful example for your case, along with test data

#### ImageData struct

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t    _limit; 
    uint32_t    _imgC; // argc
    Record**    _imgV; // argv

}   ImageData;
```

- `ImageData` here is a dynamic struct with a capacity of `_limit` `Record` data structs.
- `imgC`is the actual number of records in use
- `Record**` is a pointer to an array of pointers of `Record` structs of variable length of 1, 2,4 or 8 bytes pixels data. In this way it can hold at the same time any number of pixel data of any size
- this is the exact same thing as the `argc`/`argv` pair in `main()`

#### the `Record` struct

```
typedef void Data;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t     _id; // 1,2,4 or 8
    uint32_t    _NumPix; // argc
    Data*       _data; // argv

}   Record;     // one record of image data
```

- `_id` is the Pixel data length
- `_NumPix` is the total of pixels, as you presented
- here things are different than they were in your program: the pixel data is allocated here, and is an area of `_id * _NumPix` bytes with the pixel data in sequence, like in my bitmap building program I changed to use your data ;)
- the pixel data are packed here in groups of `_id` and unpacked as needed, using nothing but a `void*` pointer.

#### The example

I used random data and a "factory" function that builds and returns random 1- 2- 4- or 8-byte images

#### the *pixel factory* function

```
Record* getImage()
{

    const uint8_t len[4] = { 1,2,4,8 };
    Record* one = (Record*)malloc(sizeof(Record));
    one->_id = len[rand() % 4];
    one->_NumPix = 1 + rand() % 8;
    // now builds the pixels with random values under 255
    // here the actual size of EACH record is computed
    uint32_t total = one->_NumPix * one->_id; 
    void* p = (Data**)malloc(total);
    uint8_t value = rand() % 255;
    // here you get the actual pixel data
    memset(p, value, total); 
    one->_data = (Data**)p;
    return one;
};
```

#### The program logic

- 3 constants at the start defines the run:

```
#define     _BLOCK_SIZE_ 50
#define     _IMAGES_     5
#define     _SEED_       201001
```

- Memory for images is allocated in blocks of `_BLOCK_SIZE_` `Record*` pointers. At the end of the data acquisition phase the  array is trimmed to the exact used size.

  - `_IMAGES_` is the number of images to build, All images are displayed as the ImageData array is built.
  - `_SEED` is the seed for the random data
- When the array is created the eventual unused data is `free()` so `ImageData` has just the records corresponding to the image data.
- The program then shows some random records, this time form the `ImageData` array so we can compare it with the data displayed in the building phase.

#### An example of output

```
DumpImage(Sample 0): 8 8-pixels images [64 bytes]:

     0: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC
     1: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC
     2: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC
     3: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC
     4: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC
     5: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC
     6: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC
     7: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC

DumpImage(Sample 1): 4 2-pixels images [8 bytes]:

     0: 02 02
     1: 02 02
     2: 02 02
     3: 02 02

DumpImage(Sample 2): 3 2-pixels images [6 bytes]:

     0: DC DC
     1: DC DC
     2: DC DC

DumpImage(Sample 3): 5 2-pixels images [10 bytes]:

     0: 75 75
     1: 75 75
     2: 75 75
     3: 75 75
     4: 75 75

DumpImage(Sample 4): 7 4-pixels images [28 bytes]:

     0: 54 54 54 54
     1: 54 54 54 54
     2: 54 54 54 54
     3: 54 54 54 54
     4: 54 54 54 54
     5: 54 54 54 54
     6: 54 54 54 54



5 Test images loaded
now shows 2 random images from list


DumpImage(From Array: image 3): 5 2-pixels images [10 bytes]:

     0: 75 75
     1: 75 75
     2: 75 75
     3: 75 75
     4: 75 75

DumpImage(From Array: image 0): 8 8-pixels images [64 bytes]:

     0: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC
     1: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC
     2: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC
     3: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC
     4: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC
     5: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC
     6: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC
     7: EC EC EC EC EC EC EC EC

        50 pointers allocated
        5 arguments read
        45 pointers to free
        Block size trimmed for a total of 5 pointers
        Image array is ready for use
```

The example program ends here. I did not ported the deallocation of memory, that is trivial, and wrote nothing using the data as I had no idea on that :)

Also I did not tested much. And please no *religion talk* here: Yes, I used an underline at the start of the fields of the structs. I used only the Microsoft compiler CL 16.7.4 that runs here now.

I set the numbers here to 5 records only so I could post all the output data. But as the memory is packed with just the data and the metadata is only a few words is ok to run this for many thousands of records. And it is fast.

For large data sets it is better to change the *BLOCK_SIZE* to a larger number

#### the code for the example

```
#define     _BLOCK_SIZE_ 50
#define     _IMAGES_     5
#define     _SEED_       201001

#include <math.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void Data;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t     _id; // 1,2,4 or 8
    uint32_t    _NumPix; // argc
    Data*       _data; // argv

}   Record;     // one record of image data

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t    _limit; 
    uint32_t    _imgC; // argc
    Record**    _imgV; // argv

}   ImageData;

int         dumpImage(const char*,Record*);
Record*     getImage();


int main(void)
{
    srand(_SEED_);
    char message[30];
    ImageData   image;
    image._imgC = 0;
    image._limit = _BLOCK_SIZE_;
    image._imgV = (Record**)malloc( image._limit * sizeof(Record*) );

    Record*      sandbox;
    for (int i = 0; i < _IMAGES_; i += 1)
    {
        // gets an image and a Record to hold it
        sprintf(message, "Sample %d", i);
        sandbox = getImage(); // gets a random image
        dumpImage(message, sandbox);


        Record* target = (Record*)malloc(sizeof(Record)); // new one
        target->_id = sandbox->_id;
        target->_NumPix = sandbox->_NumPix;
        uint32_t total = sandbox->_NumPix * sandbox->_id;
        target->_data = (void*)malloc(total);

        memcpy(target->_data, sandbox->_data, total);
        image._imgV[image._imgC] = target;

        // expands the block if there is no space left
        if (image._imgC >= image._limit)
        {   // block is full
            image._limit += _BLOCK_SIZE_;
            char* new_block = realloc(image._imgV, (image._limit * sizeof(char*)));
            printf("Block extended for a total of %d pointers\n", image._limit);
            image._imgV = (Record**)new_block;
        };  // if()

        image._imgC += 1;

    };  // for

    printf("\n\n%d Test images loaded\n", image._imgC);
    printf("now shows %d random images from list\n\n\n", _IMAGES_ / 2 );

    for (int i = 0; i < _IMAGES_ / 2; i += 1)
    {
        int j = rand() % _IMAGES_;
        sprintf(message, "From Array: image %d", j);
        sandbox = getImage(); // gets a random image
        dumpImage(message,image._imgV[j]);
    };  // for()


    // now trims the end of the block
    // allocated: _limit
    // used: argc
    printf("\t%d pointers allocated\n", image._limit);
    printf("\t%d arguments read\n", image._imgC);
    if (image._limit == image._imgC)
        printf("\tNothing to free()\n");
    else
    {
        printf("\t%d pointers to free\n", image._limit - image._imgC);
        char* new_size = realloc(image._imgV, (image._imgC * sizeof(char*)));
        printf("\tBlock size trimmed for a total of %d pointers\n", image._imgC);
        image._imgV = (Record**)new_size;
    };

    printf("\tImage array is ready for use\n");

    return 0;
};  // main()


int         dumpImage(const char* msg, Record* img)
{
    /*
        uint8_t     _id; // len
        uint32_t    _NumPix; // argc
        Data**      _data; // argv
     */
    uint32_t total = img->_NumPix * img->_id;
    uint8_t* p = (void*)img->_data;
    printf("DumpImage(%s): %d %d-pixels images [%d bytes]:\n\n", msg, img->_NumPix, img->_id, total);
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < img->_NumPix; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%6d: ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < img->_id; j++)
            printf("%02X ", *p);
        printf("\n");
    };  // for()
    printf("\n");
    return total;
};

//
// Image factory: build random "images"
// id is 1 to 4, NumPix is 1 to 100, 
// data is NumPix Pixels with id bytes
//
/*
    uint8_t     _id; // len
    uint32_t    _NumPix; // argc
    Data**      _data; // argv
 */
Record* getImage()
{

    const uint8_t len[4] = { 1,2,4,8 };
    Record* one = (Record*)malloc(sizeof(Record));
    one->_id = len[rand() % 4];
    one->_NumPix = 1 + rand() % 8;
    // now builds the pixels with random values under 255
    uint32_t total = one->_NumPix * one->_id;
    void* p = (Data**)malloc(total);
    uint8_t value = rand() % 255;
    memset(p, value, total);
    one->_data = (Data**)p;
    return one;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this way OK in the sense of being legit?

Sure. Btw. you can abstract away just the size, and have a function that just returns `sizeof` depending on data type, and then do `malloc(NumPix * data_get_size_of_object(DataType))`. [Real world example - a big function that returns `sizeof(type)` in a big switch](https://github.com/Gurux/GuruxDLMS.c/blob/master/development/src/cosem.c#L56).

> Is there another way doing this with less code and more generic approach?

Well, not with "less code".

You'll end up with a lot what I call "*fat* switches". Every function you'll have will be a big `switch(type) { case sometype: do_something_with_that_type((cast_to_type*)pointer); case someothertype: etc. }` which will become 1000 lines long unreadable mess of switches. It will not be flexible. Adding new functionality will be slow. Maintaining will be slow. Because you'll have to think about every case every single time, bugs will arise. Invert the thinking - it's not the function that should know what to do with the type, the *type* itself should be aware of operations. Thus the term *object oriented* programming. Create an *interface* and create *objects* that implement that interface - that way objects keep track what happens to them. [Real life example - `struct file_operations` from linux kernel](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/device_drivers.html#struct-file-operations).

My recent experiences made me to believe there is some fear associated with function pointers. A function pointer may be used for choosing what to do once and then later execute different operation depending on previous choice. One switch where function pointers are assigned and then later just a single jump to the previously assigned function. No need to choose all the time again and again. Some design with a virtual table and a interface could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct dataif_s dataif_t;

struct dataif_vtable_s {
    void (*free)(dataif_t *t); // destructor
    int (*read_data)(dataif_t *t, FILE *from); // read data from file
    int (*save)(dataif_t *t, FILE *to); // serialize data to file
    int (*fprint)(dataif_t *t, FILE *to); // print in human readable format
    int (*add)(dataif_t *t, int a); // add integer to each number
};

struct dataif_s {
    // a pointer to virtual table that implements operations
    const struct dataif_vtable_s *vtable;
    // a pointer to provide object's data
    void *priv;
};

// shortcut accessors
int dataif_read_data(dataif_t *t, FILE *from) {
     // add assert(t != NULL); etc. to ease bugs detection
     // or maybe handle 'if(t->vtable->read_data != NULL) return -ENOSYS;' ?
     return t->vtable->read_data(t, from);
}

int dataif_print(dataif_t *t) {
    return t->vtable->fprint(t, stdout);
}

void dataif_free(dataif_t *t) {
     t->vtable->free(t);
}
// etc. for each function

/* ------------------------------------------ */

// private data implementing unsigned char operations
struct bytedata_s {
    size_t count;
    unsigned char *data;
};

int bytedata_read_data(dataif_t *t, FILE *from);
void bytedata_free(dataif_t *t);

// the virutal table
// note it's static const - it's stored in .rodata, saves RAM memory
static const struct dataif_vtable_s bytedata_vtable = {
     .free = bytedata_free,
     .read_data = bytedata_read_data,
     /* etc. fill with custom function pointers */
};

// Constructor for data of unsigned chars
int bytedata_init(dataif_t *t, size_t NumPix) {
     // construct bytedata object
     struct bytedata_s *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
     if (!p) goto ERR_p;
     p->data = malloc(NumPix * sizeof(*p->data));
     if (!p->data) goto ERR_data;
     p->count = NumPix;

     // create the interface
     t->priv = p;
     t->vtable = &bytedata_vtable;

     return 0;
     free(p->data);
     ERR_data:
     free(p);
     ERR_p:
     return -ENOMEM; 
}

// reading values
int bytedata_read_data(dataif_t *t, FILE *from) {
    struct bytedata_s *p = t->priv; // extract out object
    for (size_t i = 0; i < p->count; ++i) {
        if (fscanf(from, "%hhu", &p->data[i]) != 1) return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void bytedata_free(dataif_t *t) {
     // free data allocated in constructor
     struct bytedata_s *p = t->priv;
     free(p->data);
     free(t->priv);
}

/* ---------------------------------------------- */

// create same interfaces for each type
// note - only one single function is visible externally
// all other functions are accessible via virtual table
int int32data_init(dataif_t *t, size_t NumPix);
int float32data_init(dataif_t *t, size_t NumPix);
int float64data_init(dataif_t *t, size_t NumPix);

/* ---------------------------------------------- */

// map value types to constructors, ie. "object factory"
typedef enum {
    DATATYPE_BYTE,     //unsigned char
    DATATYPE_INT32,    //int
    DATATYPE_FLOAT32,  //float
    DATATYPE_FLOAT64,  //double 
} datatype_t; // I will not use UpperCamelCase

// map of datatypes to constructors
static const int (*dataif_inits[])(dataif_t *t, size_t NumPix) = {
    [DATATYPE_BYTE] = bytedata_init,
    [DATATYPE_INT32] = int32data_init,
    [DATATYPE_FLOAT32] = float32data_init,
    [DATATYPE_float64] = float64data_init,
};

int dataif_init(dataif_t *t, datatype_t datatype, size_t NumPix) {
    if (datatype < 0 || datatype > sizeof(dataif_inits)/sizeof(*dataif_inits)) {
        // the datatype not found in the array
        return -EINVAL;
    }
    // note how the switch... doesn't exists anymore.
    return dataif_inits[datatype](t, NumPix);
}

# if 0
// if enum values doesn't start from zero
// use a structure and a for to find the mapping between an enum to constructor
struct datatype_to_init_s {
     datatype_t t;
     int (*init)(dataif_t *t, size_t NumPix);
};
static const struct datatype_to_init_s datatype_to_init[] = {
     { DATATYPE_BYTE, bytedata_init },
     /* etc. */
};
int dataif_init(dataif_t *t, datatype_t datatype, size_t NumPix) {
    // find datatype in datatype_to_init
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(datatype_to_init)/sizeof(*datatype_to_init); ++i) {
         if (datatype_to_init[i].t == datatype) {
             // found it? create the object
             return datatype_to_init[i].init(NumPix);
         }
    }
    // the datatype not found in the array
    return -EINVAL;
}
# endif

/* ---------------------------------------------- */

size_t image_get_size(const char *);
datatype_t image_get_datatype(const char *);
static const char *image = "/tmp/a.png";

int main() {
     int err = 0;
     size_t numpix = image_get_size(image);
     datatype_t thedatatype  = image_get_datatype(image);
     FILE *some_file = fopen(image, "r");
     if (some_file == NULL) { err = -1; goto ERR_fopen; }

     dataif_t data;
     err = dataif_init(&data, thedatatype, numpix); // initializes data depending on datatype
     if (err) goto ERR_dataif_init; // add a friendly error message

     err = dataif_read_data(&data, some_file);
     if (err) goto ERR_read_data; 

     dataif_do_something(&data);
     dataif_print(&data);

     ERR_read_data:
     dataif_free(&data);
     ERR_dataif_init:
     fclose(some_file);
     ERR_fopen:
     return err;
}
```